Connecting to WireGuard no Internet Access
I'm using an old laptop as a Home server and I wanted to set up a VPN (Wireguard & DuckDNS using PiVPN) following this guide: https://chriskalos.notion.site/The-0-Home-Server-Written-Guide-5d5ff30f9bdd4dfbb9ce68f0d914f1f6#4395816a03b5400e8b8634b578b66f40
so I got my Domain from DuckDNS and I set a Static DHCP like this: https://imgur.com/a/Y18BGgS
and I forwarded the port in my router following this guide: https://portforward.com/vodafone/gigabox/
this is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/4TsSxti
when setting up pivpn I selected:

WireGuard as Installation mode

the default wireguard port: 51820

DNS provider: CloudFlare

Public IP or DNS: DNS Entry

Public DNS name of this server: <mydns>.duckdns.org and the Rebbot of the system


then I added a pivpn with pivpn add then pivpn -qr to generate a QR code I opened my WireGuard from my phone scanned the QR code and connected to my VPN but there was no internet connection in my phone.
this is a screenshot of my configuration: https://imgur.com/a/ge6TPek
sudo wg output with my phone connected to the VPN using mobile data :
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo wg
interface: wg0
  public key: xxxxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820
  fwmark: 0xca6c

peer: xxxxxx
  preshared key: (hidden)
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0

My router info:
Firmware version: Vodafone-H-300s-v1.0.11.05
WAN IPv4 Address: 212.xxx.xxx.xx
WAN IPv6 Address: 

My Public IPv4 using whatismyip is: 212.xxx.xxx.xx
ipvpn debug output: https://pastebin.pl/view/9d8a1fc2
any help, please? Thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Community I wish I knew where the problem is, unfortunately, I don't. That's why I'm explaining everything I did

You mention Vodafone. Does your router have a public IP address? What is the output of sudo wg on your old laptop (after connecting to the VPN on your phone? Did you disconnect the phone from your local network before trying? // (Just ignore lazy flaggers and the resulting bot comments.)

@DanielB Thank you for the replay, 1- I have checked whether my router has a public IP adress or not using whatismyip and it displayed this: My Public IPv4:##.###.##.### My Public IPv6: Not Detected   2- sudo wg gives the same output whether the phone is connected or not and it's this:  ```interface: wg0
public key: xxxxxxxxx
private key: (hidden)
listening port: 51820
peer: xxxxxxxxx
preshared key: (hidden)
allowed ips: 10.#5.###.2/3# ``` ,  and yes Im on 4g when I connected to the VPN

Please put all additional information in your question. You can use proper formatting there. // Of course your traffic would eventually appear from a public IP address. Check again, in your router's UI, whether you actually have this public IP address and are not subject to CGNAT.

@DanielB I have updated my question to include my router info (Model and WAN IP) and the sudo wg output along with ipvpn debug output

That’s not it yet, sorry. You must verify that the WAN IPv4 address as reported by the router matches the WAN IPv4 address as reported by a “What is my IP”-type website. Put the result of that check in your question.

Using my static Public IP instead of DuckDNS has resolved the issue. Now, I can SSH into my home server and access all my files from it using Mobile Data. However, I'm unable to access the internet while connected to that VPN, to fix this I have followed this guide: https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/vpn/wireguard/internal/#enable-nat-on-the-server
So I Enabled NAT on the server by adding the following to the [INTERFACE] section of my /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf:
PostUp = nft add table ip wireguard; nft add chain ip wireguard wireguard_chain {type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat\; policy accept\;}; nft add rule ip wireguard wireguard_chain counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade; nft add table ip6 wireguard; nft add chain ip6 wireguard wireguard_chain {type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat\; policy accept\;}; nft add rule ip6 wireguard wireguard_chain counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
PostDown = nft delete table ip wireguard; nft delete table ip6 wireguard
